# Annotation Processor : initialize a field

Tags: android, annotation-processing, javapoet

I am writing an annotation processor in android which generates a java file. I am using `JavaPoet` library for that.

The purpose of generated file:
It should have a list of names of the classes with a particular annotation that my processor supports and provide a public method to get that list.

Now, I've generated the file:

```
 private final List<String> names;

 GeneratedFile(ArrayList<String> names) {
    this.names = names;
 }

 public List<String> getNames() {
   return names;
}
```

Now, the problem is: How do I initialize the `names` field from the processor? The `Javapoet` api provides an `initializer` for the field but that only takes a string. 
In my processor, I've the list of classes that have my supported annotation. I want to populate this field with that list.

Comment: Are you looking for a list of classes that implement your annotation und use this list to initialize the array of the generated class? Is that what you want to do?

Comment: @ElHoss:  yes ! exactly !

Answer (score 0):

As you already know, JavaPoet offers only a string to specify field initialization. To accomplish your task you have to (I will show you some code that is not specific to your problem, but it can be a good example to show you how to do it):

- **Get from your annotation processor the list of classes with your annotation** (the code is copied from a [my library](https://github.com/xcesco/kripton)):

  ```
  @Override
  public boolean process(Set<? extends TypeElement> annotations, RoundEnvironment roundEnv) {
      model = new PrefsModel();

      parseBindType(roundEnv);

      // Put all @BindSharedPreferences elements in beanElements
      for (Element item : roundEnv.getElementsAnnotatedWith(BindSharedPreferences.class)) {
          AssertKripton.assertTrueOrInvalidKindForAnnotationException(item.getKind() == ElementKind.CLASS, item, BindSharedPreferences.class);

        // store type name somewhere
      }

      return true;
  }
  ```
- Use this set of TypeName to generate the initial value for you field:

  ```
  ...
  Builder sp = FieldSpec.builder(ArrayTypeName.of(String.class), "COLUMNS", Modifier.STATIC, Modifier.PRIVATE,
      Modifier.FINAL);
  String s = "";
  StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
  for (SQLProperty property : entity.getCollection()) {
    buffer.append(s + "COLUMN_" + 
       columnNameToUpperCaseConverter.convert(property.getName()));
   s = ", ";
  }
  classBuilder.addField(sp.addJavadoc("Columns array\n").initializer("{" + 
    buffer.toString() + "}").build());    
  ...
  ```

You will find my library on [github](https://github.com/xcesco/kripton). In particular, you have to read the class `com.abubusoft.kripton.processor.sqlite.BindTableGenerator`.

Hope this information can be still useful.